# How to access the Date & time in the Settings on Windows using pywinauto?

Tags: python, pywinauto, windows-11

```
English:
Settings > Time & language > Date & Time > Set time automatically

Portuguese:
Configurações > Hora e idioma > Data e hora > Definir horário automaticamente
```

My computer is not synchronizing the time when it restarts, so I want to automate this synchronization when I activate the Python code.

I want to perform the action of turning off and on the `Set time automatically` option inside a `Date & Time`:

[image]

[image]

I have tried in English (Because I noticed that even my Windows 11 in other language, "control system" is used to open "Settings"):

```python
from pywinauto import Application

#open Setting
app = Application(backend="uia").start("control system")
#open Time & language
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title="Time & language", timeout=20)
#open Date & Time
app.window(title="Time & language").child_window(title="Date & time").invoke()
#turn off
app.window(title="Date & time").child_window(title="Set time automatically", control_type="CheckBox").click()
#turn on
app.window(title="Date & time").child_window(title="Set time automatically", control_type="CheckBox").click()
```

And in portuguese (because my windows is Portuguese):

```python
from pywinauto import Application

#open Setting
app = Application(backend="uia").start("control system")
#open Time & language
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title="Hora e idioma", timeout=20)
#open Date & Time
app.window(title="Hora e idioma").child_window(title="Data e hora").invoke()
#turn off
app.window(title="Data e hora").child_window(title="Definir horário automaticamente", control_type="CheckBox").click()
#turn on
app.window(title="Data e hora").child_window(title="Definir horário automaticamente", control_type="CheckBox").click()
```

But the page always remains on the initial page of the Settings app, it doesn't move to where I want it to. What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to invoke NTP sync from python on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66610997/how-to-invoke-ntp-sync-from-python-on-windows)

Comment: Hi @esqew to be honest, I was really wanting to learn how to work with ```pywinauto``` and I took advantage of my current case to solve my doubt regarding the execution of the steps until reaching the final goal, but thanks for the suggestion because I didn't know about this recommended approach!